# Get user credentials from Sharepoint Active Directory then use it in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Hi I would like to ask if it's possible to get user credentials from Sharepoint Active Directory to ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current logged in user with javascript using the Client Side Object Model (CSOM) like this...

```
function CSOM()
{
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  this.website = context.get_web();
  this.currentUser = website.get_currentUser();
  context.load(currentUser);
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}



function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
 {
   alert("Current User: " + currentUser.get_loginName());
 }



function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
  alert('Unable to get current user ' + args.get_message() + '\n'+ args.get_stackTrace());
}
```